# com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined - HtmlUnitFactory

Tags: jquery, scala, scalatest

I'm using HtmlUnitFactory (scalatestplus),
this is my code

```
"The OneBrowserPerTest trait" must {
  "provide a web driver" in {
     go to s"http://localhost:$port/"
     pageTitle mustBe "PolicyModel Server"
  }
}
```

and I have in the main page code with jquery -

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#toggleTagLevels").click(
          function () {
               $("#tagLevels").slideToggle();
               return false;
          });
        });
</script>
```

when I run the test i get -

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (script in http://localhost:33018/ from (96, 13) to (104, 14)#97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (script in http://localhost:33018/ from (96, 13) to (104, 14)#97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
```

am I missing something? 
How can I work with HtmlUnitFactory and jquery?

tnx!

Comment: Looks like you haven't included jQuery

Comment: where should I include jquery?
The project is running.. it's only the tests